# imshow() and matplotlib() are not working together

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I have this simple OpenCV code to plot histogram of an Image.

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
import cv2

image=cv2.imread('/media/755784/New Volume/DATA/Images/opencv.jpg')

h,w=image.shape[:2]

cv2.imwrite('/media/755784/New Volume/DATA/Images/result.png',image)
print h,w

cv2.imshow("Image",image)
cv2.waitKey(0)## <--

print 'Plotting histogram'
hist=cv2.calcHist(image,[0],None,[256],[0,256])
plt.hist(image.ravel(),256,[0,256])
plt.show()
while True:
    k=cv2.waitKey(30)
    if k==27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I remove the waitKey(0) after the imshow(), the histogram gets plotted first and unless you close the plot, the image is not displayed. Is this a particular problem with python or matplotlib?

Comment: Did you read the documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html) that seems to say you must use `waitKey`?

Comment: use cv2.waitKey(1) ## non-blocking

Comment: I agree that cv2.waitKey(1) or cv2.waitKey(0) will display two windows correctly, but after 5 seconds the image window loses its brightness.. It is like python is loosing the focus out of that window.. When you close the plot window, image window regains its brightness..

Answer (score 3):

Your `plt.show()` blocks the code, so you don't get to the while loop.

But you can plot the image also with matplotlib. That makes it easier:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

image=cv2.imread('/tmp/stinkbug.png')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,3))
ax1 = plt.subplot(1,2,1)
ax1.imshow(image)
ax2 = plt.subplot(1,2,2)
ax2.hist(image.ravel(),256,[0,256])
plt.show()
```

(Note: I used a different image)

Comment: If this answer solved you problems, please consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). This will also make it clear to others that you don't need any further help (on this topic).